# Parametric surface with texture and mesh

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, parametric-functions, textures

The following code maps a parchment texture on a parametric surface:

```
f[u_, v_] := {Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]}    
g[u_, v_] := {u, v}    

tex = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cnLp.jpg"];   

ParametricPlot3D[f[u, v], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> Texture[tex], 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &) Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, 
 MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Black}, {Thick, Black}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0], Mesh -> True]
```

Here is the parchment texture image:

[image]

The problem is that I would like to show the surface mesh also and it is not rendering.

[image]

I would like to show both the mesh and the textured surface. Question is how?

Comment: Remove `Mesh -> None`.  `ParametricPlot3D[f[u, v], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> Texture[tex], 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &), Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, 
 MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Black}, {Thick, Black}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0], Mesh -> True]`

Comment: man, doh! as homer Simpson would say!